# How to get most recent data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with three pieces of data, FacilityName, DateLastVerified, & Intensity.  I want to be able to pull the records with the most recent DateLastVerified.  When the DateLastVerified is the same, then I want it to select the record with the highest Intensity.

```
|FacilityName                                   | DateLastVerified | Intensity
|Nemours/Alfred I. duPont Hospital for Children | 2014-03-01       | 16
|Boston Children's Hospital                     | 2015-11-29       | 6
|Boston Children's Hospital                     | 2017-04-01       | 3
|Tufts Medical Center                           | 2017-04-01       | 3
|Tufts Medical Center                           | 2017-04-01       | 6
```

So for the above table I'd want to return the second entry for Boston Children's Hospital and second entry for Tufts Medical Center.  How would I write this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.   Why would you be returning two records rather than just the Tufts record?  It has the highest intensity.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That is how the table is set up in the database I work in.  It's a SQL server database.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to pull the records with the most recent
>   DateLastVerified. When the DateLastVerified is the same, then I want
>   it to select the record with the highest Intensity.

Based on this description, you can get one record using `order by` and `fetch first 1 row only`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by DateLastVerified desc, Intensity desc
offset 0 row fetch first 1 row only;
```

Or for SQL Server:

```
select top 1 t.*
from t
order by DateLastVerified desc, Intensity desc;
```

Comment: FYI when I try to run that (loaded up a CTE with the data) it errors `Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 12
Invalid usage of the option first in the FETCH statement.` I think you need to include an `offset` to use a `fetch`

Comment: @Xedni . . . When I answered the question, it was not tagged "sql-server".  The `offset` clause is optional in other databases.